# Laravel query builder function whereNotBetween() usage issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Has anyone used DB::whereNotBetween() in Laravel4?

I tried using it for retrieving rows from a table where the field value is not between the given 2 dates, but failed! Here is how I tried it -

DB::table('bookings')->whereNotBetween('arrival',array("2014-01-02","2014-01-10"))->get(array('id'));

This should return all booking rows where the arrival date is not between the above given dates. But instead I am receiving the following error -

"Unknown column 'not_between' in 'where clause' "

not sure what I am doing wrong so all helps are welcomed.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whereNotBetween is a new feature in Laravel 4.1.*. Check your version with php artisan -V to be sure. If you don't have 4.1.* installed, you can easily follow [this](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) guide to upgrade from 4.0.*. I just did it twice last week and it's fairly simple.

If you are on 4.0.*, and can't upgrade for some reason, I would suggest going back to the old tried-and-true: `where(...,'>=', $enddate)->where(..., '<=', $startdate)`.

Comment: Np. Glad it was something simple. ;)